# WatchKit local notification does not fire when simulator is locked

Tags: swift, notifications, ios9, watchkit, watchos-2

Assume you have an application for iOS that schedule a local notification. When the notification is fired, it is showed in the iPhone simulator. If the iPhone simulator is locked, the notification is showed in the Watch simulator, but only if the application is not active and the simulator is not locked.

The notification is not shown in this scenario:

- the iPhone simulator is locked;
- the Watch simulator was running the app but it is locked with Command+L.

The notification is also not shown in this scenario:

- the iPhone simulator is locked;
- the Watch simulator was running the app;
- the user switch to the watch face;
- the user lock the simulator with Command+L.

In these two cases, the notification is not shown in either the simulators. If you unlock the Watch simulator with Command+L, the notification is immediately shown.

I also noted that if the simulator is locked the `WKExtensionDelegate.didReceiveLocalNotification` method is not called; this method is however called if the app is running but the simulator is not locked.

It seems that the beaviour is consistent with real devices. This happens with iOS 9 / watchOS 2.

The notification is configured as follows:

```
notification.alertBody = "Tempo scaduto"
notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
notification.category = "style0"
notification.fireDate = date
notification.userInfo = dictionary
```

In the scenarios mentioned, the notification is "lost", as it isn't displayed to the user and there is no callback to app code to manage that manually.